# creating layout for my website but i cannt edit div tag?

Tags: html, css, layout

Hello i was creating simple layout but when i want to style footer it does not dislplay in the output , ? what could be the problem ? see i have applied style on footer and its back ground color is not displaying .
image is here : http://oi40.tinypic.com/xe03rs.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container {
        width: 950px;
        height: auto;
        margin:auto;
    }
    #header {
        width: 950px;
        height:120px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
#main {
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color:#0F0;
    float:left;
}
#sidebar {
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#00F;
    float:left;
}
#footer {
    width: 950px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color:#F00;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    HEADER GOES HERE
    </div>

    <div id="main">
    MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR GOES HERE
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    FOOTER GOES HERE
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The styling is working but your footer was hidden by other elements, try:

```
#footer {
width: 950px;
height: 500px;
background-color:#F00;
float: left;
}
```

Here goes the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tMFm/40/

Answer (score 1):

You have two `divs` `main` and `sidebar` which are `floating` using `float:left;`

so in order to make `footer` visible you need to add `clear:both` property for footer because `div` are **block level element** and when you add `float` they will be behave like normal `inline DOM`,

```
#footer {
    width: 950px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color:#F00;
    clear:both;
  --^^^^^^^^^^^-----
}
```

now see the changes. It must work.

Comment: thanks so much sir . This code is better,i have added clear:both and its working. ^^

Comment: @user2555871 well keep in mind `floating divs` are hard to maintain if you do not care pixels...Otherwise You can play with it.

Answer (score 0):

set for #container

```
overflow: auto;
```

and for #footer

```
margin: auto;
```